# В классе, функция в функции не срабатывает

Tags: php

Выдает ошибку: [ Call to undefined function fun2() ... ], как выполнить fun2?

```html
<?php
 class User {
     
  public function fun1($arg1,$arg2)
  {
                    echo '<br>Start fun1;';
                    fun2($arg1);
  }
  
  public function fun2($arg1) {
      echo '<br>Start fun2;';
  }
  
 }
 
 $user = new User();
 $arg1 = $_REQUEST['arg1'];
 $arg2 = $_REQUEST['arg2'];
 $user-> fun1($arg1,$arg2);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод того же объекта:

```
$this->fun2($arg1);
```

Comment: Как не странно, но такое уже пробывал, и не срабатывало, и только после такого как задал вопрос на stackoverflow - сработало. 
p.s. правильно будет $this->fun2($arg1);